# What's the difference between [A,B] and [A;B] in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, syntax

```
%   CAT(2,A,B) is the same as [A,B].
%   CAT(1,A,B) is the same as [A;B].
```

Seems I need to know this to understand what `cat` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[A,B]
```

is a matrix formed by placing B to the right of A, while

```
[A;B]
```

is a matrix formed by placing B below A.

Learn also about `horzcat` and `vertcat`.

Comment: So each operator in matlab can be regarded as an operator for matrix?

Answer (score 3):

```
[A, B] does col cat
[A; B] does row cat
```

eg:

```
x = [1, 2, 3];
y = [7, 8, 9];

[x, y] == > [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]

becomes a 1x6 array




[x; y] == > [1, 2, 3]
            [7, 8, 9]

becomes a 2x3 array
```

Just try it in Matlab and open ans to see the difference